# Roslyn Autocomplete exception with Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Tags: c#, sharepoint, reference, roslyn

I'm making C# editor with autocomplete for SharePoint using older version of Roslyn because it provides scripting engine.
For getting completion items I'm using same approach as [here](http://arbel.net/2013/05/11/roslynpad/) or possibly [here](http://github.com/khellang/scriptcs-editor).

It works fine, but when I add reference to "Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"

```
private static readonly Type[] _assemblyTypes = new[]
{
 typeof (object), 
 typeof (Uri), 
 typeof (Enumerable),
 typeof (StringWriter),
 typeof (SPContext), //for 'Microsoft.SharePoint' autocomplete throws an exception
 typeof (ClientContext),       //for 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client'
 typeof (ClientRuntimeContext) //and 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime' 
                               //autocomplete works without problem
};
```

I'm getting an exception when trying to get completion. (in scripting engine the same reference executes fine, so it is loading right)

> 'Roslyn.Compilers.MetadataReader.UnsupportedSignatureContent'

here is the completion method where exception occurs:

```
public IList<CompletionItem> GetCompletion(int position)
    {
        var groups = _completionService.GetGroups(GetCurrentDocument(), position,
                                             CompletionTriggerInfo.CreateInvokeCompletionTriggerInfo(),
                                             _completionService.GetDefaultCompletionProviders(),
                                             CancellationToken.None);
        return (groups ?? Enumerable.Empty<CompletionItemGroup>()).SelectMany(t => t.Items).ToArray();
    }
```

more specifically while executing this:

```
private MethodBase GetMethod(MethodBase method)
    {
        return _innerType.GetMethod(method.Name, method.GetParameters().Select(t => t.ParameterType).ToArray());
    }
```

and here is full stack trace of the exception:

> - at
>     Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Metadata.PE.MetadataDecoder.GetCorElementTypeFromTypeSymbol(TypeSymbol type)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Compilers.MetadataReader.MetadataDecoder`4.DecodeCustomAttributeNamedArgument(Int32 paramCount, MemoryReader& ppArgs)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Compilers.MetadataReader.MetadataDecoder`4.GetCustomAttribute(UInt32 customAttributeRid, CommonTypedConstant[]& positionalArgs, KeyValuePair`2[]& namedArgs)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Metadata.PE.PEAttributeData.get_CommonConstructorArguments()
> - at
>     Roslyn.Services.Shared.Extensions.ISymbolExtensions.IsBrowsingProhibitedByTypeLibAttributeWorker(ISymbol symbol, ReadOnlyArray`1 attributes, List`1 attributeConstructors, Int32 hiddenFlag)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Services.Shared.Extensions.ISymbolExtensions.IsEditorBrowsable(ISymbol symbol, Boolean hideAdvancedMembers, CommonCompilation compilation, IMethodSymbol editorBrowsableAttributeConstructor, List`1 typeLibTypeAttributeConstructors, List`1 typeLibFuncAttributeConstructors, List`1 typeLibVarAttributeConstructors)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Services.Completion.CompletionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.b__0(T s)
> - at
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e(TSource x)
> - at
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e(TSource x)
> - at
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
> - at
>     System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
> - at
>     System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
> - at 
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
> - at 
>     System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> - at 
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
> - at 
>     Roslyn.Services.Implementation.Completion.CompletionProviders.AbstractSymbolCompletionProvider.CreateItems(IDocument document, Int32 position, IEnumerable`1 symbols, Nullable`1 contextOpt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> - at 
>     Roslyn.Services.CSharp.Completion.CompletionProviders.SymbolCompletionProvider.GetCompletionsForExpressionOrStatementContext(IDocument document, Int32 position, Boolean isDebugger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> - at 
>     Roslyn.Services.CSharp.Completion.CompletionProviders.SymbolCompletionProvider.GetItemsWorker(IDocument document, Int32 position, CompletionTriggerInfo triggerInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> - at 
>     Roslyn.Services.Implementation.Completion.CompletionProviders.AbstractCompletionProvider.GetGroup(IDocument document, Int32 position, CompletionTriggerInfo triggerInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Services.Completion.CompletionService.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__1(ICompletionProvider p)
> - at
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
> - at
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
> - at
>     System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> - at
>     System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Services.Completion.CompletionService.GetGroups(IDocument documentOpt, IText text, Int32 position, CompletionTriggerInfo triggerInfo, IEnumerable`1 completionProviders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> - at
>     Roslyn.Services.Completion.CompletionService.GetGroups(IDocument document, Int32 position, CompletionTriggerInfo triggerInfo, IEnumerable`1 completionProviders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> - --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> - at
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> - at
>     C_Sharp_Console.Utilities.ReflectionExtensions.Invoke[T](MethodBase method, Object target, Object[] parameters)
> - at
>     C_Sharp_Console.CompletionServiceWrapper.Invoke(MethodBase method, Object[] parameters)
> - at
>     C_Sharp_Console.CompletionServiceWrapper.GetGroups(IDocument document, Int32 position, CompletionTriggerInfo triggerInfo, IEnumerable`1 completionProviders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> - at
>     C_Sharp_Console.InteractiveManager.GetCompletion(Int32 position)
> - at
>     CSharpConsole.CSConsole.GetAutocomplete(NameValueCollection request)

Comment: Please include the full stack of the exception. Have you also tried it with the current version of the Roslyn bits? The version you're using is over a year and a half out of date.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski ok, I specified the exception. Regarding the current version of Roslyn I have not tried it yet, because currently it does not have scripting engine and I could not find completion provider either.